# Hazelcast Jet multiple outbound edges

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I need to populate the result of aggregation to 3 separate sinks - maps where updating logic is slightly different. I tried to convert pipeline object into a DAG and add another edge to second last vertex but it threw an exception that multiple outbound edges were not allowed. Is there any way to create DAG with multiple outbound edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just able to assign the stage you want to drain to multiple sinks to a variable and then repeatedly call `drainTo()` on it with different sinks.

Example:

```
StreamStage<TimestampedEntry<..>> stage = pipeline.drawFrom(..)
                             .map(..)
                             .groupingKey(..)
                             .window(..)
                             .aggregate(counting());

stage.drainTo(Sinks.map("map1));
stage.drainTo(Sinks.map("map2")).
```

If you want to achieve the same using DAG API then you need to assign them to different *ordinals* using the `Edge.from().to()` construct. However if you are already starting with a pipeline this should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for code. I somehow found `toDag()` method in pipeline API and added more vertexes using it.